# Cannot copy text to clipboard on macOS with tmux from terminal session

Tags: tmux

The version I am running is `tmux 3.3a`

I cannot copy text to my clipboard when i scroll up in a terminal session. This seems to be because the text i'm highlightning is yellow in color rather than clear. I cannot scroll up in my tmux history and copy text to my clipboard with `fn` + `cmd+c`.

If I do not scroll the tmux session, copying to my clipboard works correctly when i press `fn` + `cmd+c`.

Here is an image that shows text that I *cannot* copy to my clipboard with `fn` + `cmd+c`.

[image]

Here is my `tmux.conf`

```
set -g mouse on
bind -n WheelUpPane if-shell -F -t = "#{mouse_any_flag}" "send-keys -M" "if -Ft= '#{pane_in_mode}' 'send-keys -M' 'select-pane -t=; copy-mode -e; send-keys -M'"
bind -n WheelDownPane select-pane -t= \; send-keys -M
bind -n C-WheelUpPane select-pane -t= \; copy-mode -e \; send-keys -M
bind -T copy-mode-vi    C-WheelUpPane   send-keys -X halfpage-up
bind -T copy-mode-vi    C-WheelDownPane send-keys -X halfpage-down
bind -T copy-mode-emacs C-WheelUpPane   send-keys -X halfpage-up
bind -T copy-mode-emacs C-WheelDownPane send-keys -X halfpage-down

# To copy, left click and drag to highlight text in yellow,
# once you release left click yellow text will disappear and will automatically be available in clibboard
# # Use vim keybindings in copy mode
setw -g mode-keys vi

# Update default binding of `Enter` to also use copy-pipe
unbind -T copy-mode-vi Enter
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -selection c"
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -in -selection clipboard"
set -g visual-bell on

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374907/tmux-mouse-copy-mode-jumps-to-bottom
unbind -T copy-mode-vi MouseDragEnd1Pane
```

Comment: Why unbind the MouseDragEnd1Pane in the last line?

Comment: Otherwise i have this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32374907/tmux-mouse-copy-mode-jumps-to-bottom